# LaTeX beamer: How to use "squeeze" option only for part of a slide?

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists

I'm using the `beamer` package for a presentation. On some slide, I have two lists, one long list on the left with many short items, one short list on the right with some explanations. The list on the left only fits onto the slide when using the `squeeze` option. The right list, however, then looks too compressed.

Is there a way to make the `squeeze` option only apply to the left list?

---

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[squeeze] % <- squeeze option
  \frametitle{Title}
  % two-column layout
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[T]{4cm}
      \centering
      % left: long list with short items
      \begin{block}{}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item $e$
          \item $\mu$
          \item $\mu \lor e$
          \item $\mu \land e$
          \item $\mu\mu$
          \item $ee$
          \item $ee \lor \mu$
          \item $ee \lor e$
          \item $\mu\mu \lor e$
          \item $\mu\mu \lor \mu$
          \item $\mu\mu \lor ee$
          \item $(e \land \mu) \lor \mu\mu$
          \item $(e \land \mu) \lor ee$
          \item $(e \land \mu) \lor ee \lor e$
          \item $(e \land \mu) \lor ee \lor \mu$
          \item $(e \land \mu) \lor \mu\mu \lor \mu$
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \hfill
    \begin{column}[T]{6cm}
      \centering
      % right: shorter list with explanations / remarks  <- this would be nicer if not squeezed
      \begin{block}{}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Many combinations
          \item Single and di-object trigger
          \item Also works for jet triggers
          \item Primary goal lepton triggers \\
            (plateau efficiency below $1$)
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}

  % another box at the bottom
  \begin{block}{}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item $\lor$: logical OR, $\land$: logical AND
      \item $ee$: di-electron trigger etc.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try and play around with different values for `\setlength{\itemsep}{1ex}` within one of the `itemize` environments. `\itemsep` is added to the normal `\parsep` so you can also use negative values.

Comment: Just did. Wanted to do it properly and not just completely guess the value as I did in the comment :)

Answer (score 7):

Try something like `\setlength{\itemsep}{.5ex}` within one of the `itemize` environment. `\itemsep` is added to the normal `\parsep` so you can also use negative values, too. I used .5ex but you can adjust that to your personal taste:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[squeeze] % <- squeeze option
  \frametitle{Title}
  % two-column layout
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[T]{4cm}
      \centering
      % left: long list with short items
      \begin{block}{}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item $e$
          \item $\mu$
          \item $\mu \lor e$
          \item $\mu \land e$
          \item $\mu\mu$
          \item $ee$
          \item $ee \lor \mu$
          \item $ee \lor e$
          \item $\mu\mu \lor e$
          \item $\mu\mu \lor \mu$
          \item $\mu\mu \lor ee$
          \item $(e \land \mu) \lor \mu\mu$
          \item $(e \land \mu) \lor ee$
          \item $(e \land \mu) \lor ee \lor e$
          \item $(e \land \mu) \lor ee \lor \mu$
          \item $(e \land \mu) \lor \mu\mu \lor \mu$
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \hfill
    \begin{column}[T]{6cm}
      \centering
      % right: shorter list with explanations / remarks  <- this would be
      % nicer if not squeezed
      \begin{block}{}
        \begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{.5ex}
          \item Many combinations
          \item Single and di-object trigger
          \item Also works for jet triggers
          \item Primary goal lepton triggers \\
            (plateau efficiency below $1$)
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}

  % another box at the bottom
  \begin{block}{}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item $\lor$: logical OR, $\land$: logical AND
      \item $ee$: di-electron trigger etc.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: result of MWE]