# Vertical space inserted before itemize environment at the top of a minipage in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

**See bottom for an updated MWE and more analysis after touhami's feedback.**

The problem I'm seeing is that an `itemize` environment at the top of a beamer `column` (`columns` with [t] alignment) introduces a blank line. I was trying to align the lines of `itemize` in a column with the text lines in the other column, so I changed the relevant parameters (`\topsep` and `\itemsep`) modifiying some code from the beamer class. However, the issue is not caused by such modification; indeed, if I comment the lines in the preamble (see the MWE), the effect is still there. I keep them in the minimal example so that it is evident that the inserted vertical space corresponds to exactly one line. I can fix the vertical space by inserting `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` at the beginning of the column in every slide with this problem, but I would like to know if there is a way to fix it globally in a presentation.

Some comments:

- If the `columns` aligment is changed to [T], the vertical space is reduced, but the lines in the two columns are no more aligned.
- This only happens if the `itemize` environment is at the top of the column: if some text is added before the environment, no vertical space is inserted and the lines are aligned.
- The order of the columns does not matter: the problem also appears if the `itemize` environment is in the first one.

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%%% These lines are a modified version of the code from the beamer 
%%% class (file beamerbaselocalstructure.sty). If they are commented
%%% out, the effect is still present\makeatletter
\makeatletter
\def\@listi{
  \leftmargin\leftmargini
  \topsep  0pt
  \parsep  0pt
  \itemsep 0pt
}
\let\@listI\@listi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  % If this is changed to [T] the lines are not aligned
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \column{5cm}
    This is some text only to show the alignment (or the lack of it)
    between this column and the following one which starts with an
    itemize environment.
    \column{5cm}
    %%% This vertical space corresponds to normal a text line, but
    %%% only happens if the itemize environment is at the beginning of
    %%% the column: indeed if we uncomment the next line, the items do
    %%% not move.
    % Something
    %%% This is a manual workaround, but I'd prefer a global fix
    % \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First
    \item Second
    \item Third
    \item Fourth
    \end{itemize}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**(Edit)** In the case of `T` alignment, the problem can be solved by also setting `\partopsep` to zero, as suggested by Ignasi in his comment, but this does not work with `t` alignment. Then, looking at the difference between the two alignment options at the beginning of touhami's answer, I cannot see why the extra vertical space is inserted. It seem that it can be suppressed by `\notinterlineskip`, but why is it inserted in the first place?

**(Update)**
The problem is present also when the `itemize` environment is at the top of a `minipage` (on which beamer `column`s are based). Therefore another MWE that shows the issue is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\@listi{
  \leftmargin\leftmargini
  \topsep  0pt
  \parsep  0pt
  \itemsep 0pt
}
\let\@listI\@listi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
    This is a minipage with some text to show the issue.
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
    Text in the top line.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item An item.
    \item A second item.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  \vspace{3ex}

  \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
    This is a minipage with some text to show the issue.
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Item in the top line.
    \item A second item.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the MWE]

As you can see, if there is a text line at the top of a minipage on the right (first case), the lines of the `itemize` environment are properly aligned with those in the left minipage. On the other hand, if the `itemize` environment is at the top of the minipage some vertical space is inserted. After some further investigations I came to the following conclusions:

- The inserted vertical space is smaller that that in the first MWE, but it becomes the same if I add `\leavevmode` before `\begin{itemize}` (as in the definition of beamer `column` environment).
- The issue is caused by the beamer class: if `documentclass` is changed to `article` (and the `frame` environment is removed) no vertical space is inserted.
- However, the issue does not seem to be related to the redefinition of `itemize` environment by the `beamer` class. If I comment the code in lines 240-265 of `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` in which `\itemize` and `\enditemize` are redefined, the beamer item markers disappear but the vertical space stays the same.

Comment: I think you also need `\partopsep 0pt` as [Andrew Swann](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94189/1952) explains. I've tested with your code and it seems to work.

Comment: @ignasi It seems to me that it works, but only when the optional argument of `columns` environment is changed to `T`. I'd prefer a solution that works with `t` alignment because in my real-world case I'm using a custom environment with `\begin{columns}[t]` but, if nobody comes up with it, I'll try to see if I can change the definition of such environment.

Answer (score 2):

**Update (just a comment)** as one can see from this code, the problem is not related to `\column` command (`minipage` is behind). It seems that the source of problem is `\itemize` (or deeper `\list`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
These lines are a modified version of the code from the beamer 
 class (file beamerbaselocalstructure.sty). If they are commented
 out, the effect is still present
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}%\vskip-1ex
%These lines are a modified versio
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First
    \item Second
    \item Third
    \item Fourth
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is a solution. By default

```
\define@key{beamer@col}{t}[true]{\def\beamer@colmode{t}\def\beamer@colalign{t}\def\beamer@colheadskip{}}
\define@key{beamer@col}{T}[true]{\def\beamer@colmode{T}\def\beamer@colalign{t}\def\beamer@colheadskip{\vskip-1ex\nointerlineskip}}
```

so one can try

```
\define@key{beamer@col}{t}[true]{\def\beamer@colmode{t}\def\beamer@colalign{t}\def\beamer@colheadskip{\vskip-1ex\nointerlineskip}}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%%% These lines are a modified version of the code from the beamer 
%%% class (file beamerbaselocalstructure.sty). If they are commented
%%% out, the effect is still present\makeatletter
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamer@col}{t}[true]{\def\beamer@colmode{t}\def\beamer@colalign{t}\def\beamer@colheadskip{\vskip-1ex\nointerlineskip}}
\def\@listi{
  \leftmargin\leftmargini
  \topsep  0pt
  \parsep  0pt
  \itemsep 0pt
}
\let\@listI\@listi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  % If this is changed to [T] the lines are not aligned
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \column{5cm}
    This is some text only to show the alignment (or the lack of it)
    between this column and the following one which starts with an
    itemize environment.
    \column{5cm}
    % This vertical space corresponds to normal a text line, but
    %%% only happens if the itemize environment is at the beginning of
    %%% the column: indeed if we uncomment the next line, the items do
    %%% not move.
    % Something
    %%% This is a manual workaround, but I'd prefer a global fix
    % \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First
    \item Second
    \item Third
    \item Fourth
    \end{itemize}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

> [image]

Comment: With your solution one would have also to add the line suggested in Ignasi comment: as you can see in the first picture, the lines of the second column are not aligned with those of the first one. If I understand correctly, the point of this solution is to make `t` alignment behave like `T`: is it so? In that case i could more easily change `t` to `T`: the problem would be to check the effect in the rest of the presentation.

Comment: @LucaD you're right. You can see http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#page=125

Comment: @LucaD answer updated a comment added.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to your feedback I've updated the MWE in the question and added some further analysis.

Comment: I'm not marking the answer as accepted because it does not fully solve the issue, but I'm assigning the bounty because it helped me to better understand the problem.

Comment: @LucaD I agree with you, and I am sorry I can't be more helpful.