# Beamer itemize not aligned when in blocks

Tags: beamer

While making a poster, I've got two columns with blocks with itemize inside them. MWE:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{} 

%\leavevmode
\begin{columns}[t, onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{block}{Contributions}
\begin{itemize}
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{block}{Approach}
\begin{itemize}
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My local installation and ShareLaTeX would misalign the bullets(baselines added by me): [image: bug illustration]

This problem seems similar to:

- [beamer: Top-aligning columns within a top-aligned frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16447/beamer-top-aligning-columns-within-a-top-aligned-frame)
- [How to modify itemize vertical spacing within blocks in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94066/how-to-modify-itemize-vertical-spacing-within-blocks-in-beamer/94189#94189)
- [Vertical space inserted before itemize environment at the top of a minipage in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270506/vertical-space-inserted-before-itemize-environment-at-the-top-of-a-minipage-in-b)

But this time it happens when itemize is inside the block. If one removes the blocks it works fine.

Am I missing something or does it look like a Beamer bug?

Thanks! I'm a LaTeX noob, sorry if I missed something stupid.

Comment: To work around this bug, you may add `\vphantom{Ag}` in each title of your blocks.

Comment: That's a very mysterious workaround that just worked! Appending this after in the beamer theme after \insertblocktitle seems to have worked too. Thanks!

I'll still submit this to beamer maintainers...

Comment: In your example, the depth of the first title is null (no letter as `g` or `y`...). `\vphantom` add a vertical phantom of its content.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: Btw I put on a bug report at https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issues/339/beamer-itemize-not-aligned-when-in-blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the depth of the first title is null (no letter as `g` or `y`). To work around this feature (or "bug") of beamer, you may add `\vphantom{Ag}` in each title of your blocks (`\vphantom` adds a vertical phantom of its content).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{} 
  \begin{columns}[t, onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{Contributions\vphantom{Ag}}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item First Item
        \item Second Item
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{Approach\vphantom{Ag}}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item First Item
        \item Second Item
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note: if you use `onlytextwidth`, the sum of the width of your columns should be lesser than `\textwidth` (to get a space between your columns).

Comment: Thanks for this workaround, accepting it as an answer. Hope Beamer devs will check up on this.

Answer (score 1):

In case one prefers a tighter vertical spacing, the following answer ignores the descending parts of the letters:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=red!30,fg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\strut\insertblocktitle\vskip-\dp\strutbox%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{This title has a problem}
    some text
\end{block}
\begin{block}{This title is about fine}
    some text
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It it possible to achieve a vertically centered layout (considering only the baseline and cap height)? Assuming that `\dp\strutbox` is equivalent to `0.3\baselineskip`, I think that something between `0.2\baselineskip` and `0.25\baselineskip` would look best, but unfortunately the result seems to depend on the font...

Comment: @JakubKlinkovský Isn't this vertically centred? If I measure the space below and above the `T` are equal.

Comment: @JakubKlinkovský In any case, if you find `\vskip-\dp\strutbox` too much try with `\vskip-.66\dp\strutbox` or whatever you like.

Comment: In the posted image, there is `10px` of red above the `T`, but only `8px` below it. I think that I've already found the ideal dimension for the fonts in my current project, but obviously it would be great to have a solution guaranteed to not depend on any particular font.