# Wrong vertical spacing in block title in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, spacing

I've adapted the example from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33231/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-block-within-a-custom-beamer-sty-theme-file/33232#33232):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=red!30,fg=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{This title has a problem}
    some text
\end{block}
\begin{block}{This title is about fine}
    some text
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The second title looks fine, but the first one looks wrong - due to the "p" crossing the baseline. How can I fix that?

Comment: This was actually fixed yesterday, see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/c09ad1f62c980b34404975cb1b6c4d8aef12f8bf and see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332463/beamer-itemize-not-aligned-when-in-blocks for the work around

Comment: The workaround involving `\vphantom{Ag}` makes all titles look like the first one. So the height is the same, but they are all top-aligned as well, which still looks wrong. Is it possible to apply the vphantom fix automatically to every block title so that I can insert a custom strut instead?

Comment: You could simply use the fixed version by placing https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/c09ad1f62c980b34404975cb1b6c4d8aef12f8bf/base/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemedefault.sty in your working directory

Comment: That still does not do what I want due to the top-alignment, but I can edit the file based on the upstream fix...

Comment: I added another answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378502/36296