# Vertically Align Content of Minipage

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, minipage

With latex beamer I would like to top align the content in minipages or a similar environment to the same height as if there was no minipage present.

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\setlength\pdfpageheight{1.60cm}%
\setlength\pdfpagewidth{6cm}%

\begin{frame}{A\strut}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item X
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{B\strut}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
        \vskip 0pt%
        \begin{itemize}
            \item X
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \nolinebreak%
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
        \vskip 0pt%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[fill=gray,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{C\strut}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[fill=gray,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=1cm] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As can bee seen, the `\item X` is differently top aligned in frame A and B, the `tikzpicture` is different top aligend in frame B and C, and most confusingly the difference in alignment also differs between the `\item X` and the `tikzpicture`.

[image: Different top alignment due to minipage usage]

- What is causing this different alignments?
- How can the alignment in frame B be changed to be the same as in frame A and C?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Top align not baseline aline

`\begin{minipage}[t]` aligns minipages to the baseline of the first content line.
As already used in the question, starting the `minipage` with a `\vskip 0pt%` causes the baseline to be at the top of the minipage, therefore producing true top alignment.

### Put the `minipage` into horizontal mode

To get the same behaviour in the minipage as outside, the minipage must be put into horizontal mode with `\leavemode%`, followed by `\vskip -\baselineskip%` to correct the vertical offset.

### Putting it all together

The desired effect can be created by starting every minipage as follows:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
    \leavevmode%
    \vskip 0pt%
    \vskip -\baselineskip%
```

Full minimal example:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\setlength\pdfpageheight{1.6cm}%
\setlength\pdfpagewidth{6cm}%

\begin{frame}{A\strut}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item X
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{B\strut}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}%
        \leavevmode%
        \vskip 0pt%
        \vskip -\baselineskip%
        \begin{itemize}
            \item X
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \nolinebreak%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}%
        \leavevmode%
        \vskip 0pt%
        \vskip -\baselineskip%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[fill=gray,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.55cm] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{C\strut}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[fill=gray,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=0.55cm] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

-\end{document}
```

[image: Everything properly top aligned]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you look for

[image]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.1\textwidth}
A
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item X
    \item Y
    \item Z
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[fill=gray,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm] {tikz};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Also please see--https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272260/197451 for problem with the `\itemize`

If you feel the answer is as per your requirements please upvote the answer by clicking on the red triangle at the left and the tick mark below it

Comment: The hint to the itemize problem was helpful.