# spacing within block and between blocks with list in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists, block

I am using beamer blocks in the default theme to delimit "paragraphs" in a frame. When I use a list within a block, the vertical spacing is different compared to the spacing for a block with no list, which looks odd. Specifically:

1. the spacing between the block heading and the first line of text in the block is different for simple text vs text in a list (compare blocks 1 and 2 in the MWE);
2. the spacing between a block and the one that follows is different depending on whether the first of the two includes a list or not (compare blocks 1, 2 vs blocks 2, 3 in the MWE).

Is there are way to "fix" either or both of these features?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A slide with blocks}

\begin{block}{Block 1}
    Some text.
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Block 2}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item item 1
   \item item 2
   \end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Block 3} 
  Some other text.
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

**Edit** Unlike this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94066/91555), the question and MWE here highlight how using a list within a block affects the spacing within the block and between blocks.

As explained in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94189/91555) to that question, the spacing of items in a list within a block can be changed by resetting `\topsep`, `\partosep`, and `\itemsep`. Implementing the solution in the answer appears to resolve issues 1. and 2. above.

Comment: Have you ever used a color theme? With colored blocks you can see the spacing issue more clearly. (For instance add `\usecolortheme{rose}` in preamble.) In this case, `itemize` adds extra spaces above `item 1` and below `item 2`, just like it adds spaces betweem `item 1` and `item 2`. Thus the weird spacing follows.

Comment: @Symbol 1, indeed, that does make it more visible. It is also more visible with "real" text, rather than the dummy text I used in the MWE. That said, I imagine this may be a feature rather than an issue (i.e. there is a good reason for the spacing to behave like that), but it does look weird...

Comment: While it is arguable whether or not such an extraneous spacing is necessary to emphasize  `itemize`, you are free to add negative spaces `\vspace*{-1cm}` wherever you want. But yet a better solution may be avoiding `itemize` or using `itemize` all the time. Because... come on... this is a presentation: you do not benefit from having complex structures in your slides.